# Solving an integral equation.

Tags: measure-theory, integral-equations

Let $K(x,y)=(x+y)e^{-y^2/2-xy}$. I need a constructive way (not simply verifying it is a solution) to show that $f(x)=e^{-x^2/2}$ is the solution to the integral equation:
\begin{equation}f(y)=\int_0^\infty K(x,y)f(x)\text{ d}x.\end{equation}
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you by chance derive a contraction principle on a certain Banach space (e.g. C[0,\infty) ). Then you could potentially apply Banach's Fixed Point theorem. Performing the iteration could yield the representation of $f$. However I'm not sure if this method will be succesful.

Comment: Yes, I managed to theoretically prove this way, that there should be a unique solution (up to multiplication by a constant) $f$ to the equation. However, the iteration requires the calculation of iterated kernels, which is not a nice method.